# Installing pwntools on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, installation, pip, pwntools

I am trying to install `pwntools` on macOS.

Whenever I try `pip3 install pwntools`, it pauses for a while on `Running setup.py bdist_wheel for capstone ...` and then prints `Failed building wheel for capstone` (I assume ‘capstone’ is some dependency) followed by a long error message. Here is the full output:

```
Collecting pwntools
Collecting tox>=1.8.1 (from pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/c3/64bade66e6188a0dc02689392d5c782a9eb6648b54ddc2db034aa495b6a2/tox-3.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyelftools>=0.2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (0.25)
Collecting capstone>=3.0.5rc2 (from pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/61/d66abbf007f8cd2643095131c7dcb8186cc42603aea6d5a18cddcbf390a5/capstone-3.0.5.post1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (5.4.7)
Collecting pyserial>=2.7 (from pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/e4/2a744dd9e3be04a0c0907414e2a01a7c88bb3915cbe3c8cc06e209f59c30/pyserial-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: sortedcontainers<2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (1.5.10)
Requirement already satisfied: intervaltree in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (2.1.0)
Collecting unicorn (from pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/7f/47fe864fe967e91de2d57677618cffc91bee3918f0a3cdbaa6500b36855e/unicorn-1.0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: mako>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (1.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: pypandoc in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (18.0)
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko>=1.15.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (2.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=6.0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (18.0)
Collecting ropgadget>=5.3 (from pwntools)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (2.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pysocks in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pwntools) (1.6.8)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=30.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools) (40.4.1)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/fe/5ca16d167849b980925d3bd706cda266c7435dcf21675c546374da207654/filelock-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting toml>=0.9.4 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/12/ced7105d2de62fa7c8fb5fce92cc4ce66b57c95fb875e9318dba7f8c5db0/toml-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv>=1.11.2 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b6/30/96a02b2287098b23b875bc8c2f58071c35d2efe84f747b64d523721dc2b5/virtualenv-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pluggy<1,>=0.3.0 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/e7/017c262070af41fe251401cb0d0e1b7c38f656da634cd0c15604f1f30864/pluggy-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools) (1.11.0)
Collecting py<2,>=1.4.17 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/c7/3da685ef117d42ac8d71af525208759742dd235f8094221fdaafcd3dba8f/py-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.9.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mako>=1.0.0->pwntools) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.25.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pypandoc->pwntools) (0.31.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from packaging->pwntools) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt>=3.1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (3.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pynacl>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pwntools) (2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pwntools) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pwntools) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.0->pwntools) (2018.8.24)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (1.11.5)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (0.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.7->cryptography>=1.5->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools) (2.19)
Building wheels for collected packages: capstone, unicorn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for capstone ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-install-hfg12cnd/capstone/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-wheel-ijgw4f7z --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Building C extensions
    CC      cs.o
    CC      utils.o
    CC      SStream.o
    CC      MCInstrDesc.o
    CC      MCRegisterInfo.o
    CC      arch/ARM/ARMDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/ARM/ARMInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/ARM/ARMMapping.o
    CC      arch/ARM/ARMModule.o
    CC      arch/AArch64/AArch64BaseInfo.o
    CC      arch/AArch64/AArch64Disassembler.o
    CC      arch/AArch64/AArch64InstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/AArch64/AArch64Mapping.o
    CC      arch/AArch64/AArch64Module.o
    CC      arch/Mips/MipsDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/Mips/MipsInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/Mips/MipsMapping.o
    CC      arch/Mips/MipsModule.o
    CC      arch/PowerPC/PPCDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/PowerPC/PPCInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/PowerPC/PPCMapping.o
    CC      arch/PowerPC/PPCModule.o
    CC      arch/Sparc/SparcDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/Sparc/SparcInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/Sparc/SparcMapping.o
    CC      arch/Sparc/SparcModule.o
    CC      arch/SystemZ/SystemZDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/SystemZ/SystemZInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/SystemZ/SystemZMapping.o
    CC      arch/SystemZ/SystemZModule.o
    CC      arch/SystemZ/SystemZMCTargetDesc.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86DisassemblerDecoder.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86Disassembler.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86IntelInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86ATTInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86Mapping.o
    CC      arch/X86/X86Module.o
    CC      arch/XCore/XCoreDisassembler.o
    CC      arch/XCore/XCoreInstPrinter.o
    CC      arch/XCore/XCoreMapping.o
    CC      arch/XCore/XCoreModule.o
    CC      MCInst.o
    LINK    libcapstone.dylib
  ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
  ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "___bzero", referenced from:
        _Thumb_getInstruction in ARMDisassembler.o
        _ARM_getInstruction in ARMDisassembler.o
        _AArch64_getInstruction in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _Mips_getInstruction in MipsDisassembler.o
        _Mips64_getInstruction in MipsDisassembler.o
        _PPC_getInstruction in PPCDisassembler.o
        _Sparc_getInstruction in SparcDisassembler.o
        ...
    "___memcpy_chk", referenced from:
        _SystemZ_getInstruction in SystemZDisassembler.o
    "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
    "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
        _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        ...
        ...
    "___strcpy_chk", referenced from:
        _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
    "___strncpy_chk", referenced from:
        _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
    "___tolower", referenced from:
        _A64NamedImmMapper_fromString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
    "___udivdi3", referenced from:
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
    "_atoi", referenced from:
        _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
    "_calloc", referenced from:
        _cs_mem_calloc in cs.o
       (maybe you meant: _cs_mem_calloc)
    "_free", referenced from:
        _cs_mem_free in cs.o
       (maybe you meant: _cs_free, _cs_mem_free )
    "_malloc", referenced from:
        _cs_mem_malloc in cs.o
       (maybe you meant: _cs_malloc, _cs_mem_malloc )
    "_memcpy", referenced from:
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _fill_insn in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
        _SStream_concat0 in SStream.o
    "_memmove", referenced from:
        _cs_strdup in utils.o
        _X86_Intel_printInst in X86IntelInstPrinter.o
        _X86_ATT_printInst in X86ATTInstPrinter.o
    "_realloc", referenced from:
        _cs_mem_realloc in cs.o
       (maybe you meant: _cs_mem_realloc)
    "_strchr", referenced from:
        _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
        _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
        _XCore_printInst in XCoreInstPrinter.o
    "_strcmp", referenced from:
        _name2id in utils.o
        _A64NamedImmMapper_fromString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
        _printPredicateOperand in PPCInstPrinter.o
        _PPC_alias_insn in PPCMapping.o
        _printMemOperand in SparcInstPrinter.o
        _Sparc_map_hint in SparcMapping.o
        _XCore_reg_id in XCoreMapping.o
        ...
    "_strcpy", referenced from:
        _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
    "_strlen", referenced from:
        _cs_strdup in utils.o
        _SStream_concat0 in SStream.o
        _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
        _PPC_printInst in PPCInstPrinter.o
        _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
        _Sparc_map_hint in SparcMapping.o
    "_strncmp", referenced from:
        _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
    "_strncpy", referenced from:
        _cs_disasm in cs.o
        _fill_insn in cs.o
        _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
    "_strrchr", referenced from:
        _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
        _AArch64_post_printer in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _PPC_post_printer in PPCInstPrinter.o
    "_strstr", referenced from:
        _AArch64_printInst in AArch64InstPrinter.o
        _PPC_post_printer in PPCInstPrinter.o
        _printAliasInstr in SparcInstPrinter.o
    "_vsnprintf", referenced from:
        _cs_vsnprintf in cs.o
       (maybe you meant: _cs_vsnprintf)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  make: *** [libcapstone.dylib] Error 1
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libcapstone.dylib'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for capstone
  Running setup.py clean for capstone
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unicorn ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-install-hfg12cnd/unicorn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-wheel-uwmfqniu --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Building C extensions
  cd qemu && \
    ./configure --cc="cc" --extra-cflags="-DUNICORN_HAS_X86 -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM -DUNICORN_HAS_ARMEB -DUNICORN_HAS_M68K -DUNICORN_HAS_ARM64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPSEL -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64 -DUNICORN_HAS_MIPS64EL -DUNICORN_HAS_SPARC -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -m32 -arch i386 -m64 -arch x86_64" --target-list="x86_64-softmmu, arm-softmmu, armeb-softmmu, m68k-softmmu, aarch64-softmmu, mips-softmmu, mipsel-softmmu, mips64-softmmu, mips64el-softmmu, sparc-softmmu,sparc64-softmmu,"

  ERROR: pthread check failed
         Make sure to have the pthread libs and headers installed.

  make: *** [qemu/config-host.h-timestamp] Error 1
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libunicorn.dylib'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for unicorn
  Running setup.py clean for unicorn
Failed to build capstone unicorn
Installing collected packages: filelock, toml, virtualenv, pluggy, py, tox, capstone, pyserial, unicorn, ropgadget, pwntools
  Running setup.py install for capstone ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-install-hfg12cnd/capstone/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-record-l5k9b1g9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    Building C extensions
      LINK    libcapstone.dylib
    ld: warning: The i386 architecture is deprecated for macOS (remove from the Xcode build setting: ARCHS)
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "___bzero", referenced from:
          _Thumb_getInstruction in ARMDisassembler.o
          _ARM_getInstruction in ARMDisassembler.o
          _AArch64_getInstruction in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _Mips_getInstruction in MipsDisassembler.o
          _Mips64_getInstruction in MipsDisassembler.o
          _PPC_getInstruction in PPCDisassembler.o
          _Sparc_getInstruction in SparcDisassembler.o
          ...
      "___memcpy_chk", referenced from:
          _SystemZ_getInstruction in SystemZDisassembler.o
      "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
      "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _ARM_get_insn_id in ARMMapping.o
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _decodeToMCInst in AArch64Disassembler.o
          _printInstruction in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _printTypedVectorList in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          ...
          ...
      "___strcpy_chk", referenced from:
          _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
      "___strncpy_chk", referenced from:
          _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
      "___tolower", referenced from:
          _A64NamedImmMapper_fromString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
      "___udivdi3", referenced from:
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
      "_atoi", referenced from:
          _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
      "_calloc", referenced from:
          _cs_mem_calloc in cs.o
         (maybe you meant: _cs_mem_calloc)
      "_free", referenced from:
          _cs_mem_free in cs.o
         (maybe you meant: _cs_free, _cs_mem_free )
      "_malloc", referenced from:
          _cs_mem_malloc in cs.o
         (maybe you meant: _cs_malloc, _cs_mem_malloc )
      "_memcpy", referenced from:
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _fill_insn in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
          _SStream_concat0 in SStream.o
      "_memmove", referenced from:
          _cs_strdup in utils.o
          _X86_Intel_printInst in X86IntelInstPrinter.o
          _X86_ATT_printInst in X86ATTInstPrinter.o
      "_realloc", referenced from:
          _cs_mem_realloc in cs.o
         (maybe you meant: _cs_mem_realloc)
      "_strchr", referenced from:
          _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
          _XCore_insn_extract in XCoreInstPrinter.o
          _XCore_printInst in XCoreInstPrinter.o
      "_strcmp", referenced from:
          _name2id in utils.o
          _A64NamedImmMapper_fromString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
          _printPredicateOperand in PPCInstPrinter.o
          _PPC_alias_insn in PPCMapping.o
          _printMemOperand in SparcInstPrinter.o
          _Sparc_map_hint in SparcMapping.o
          _XCore_reg_id in XCoreMapping.o
          ...
      "_strcpy", referenced from:
          _A64SysRegMapper_toString in AArch64BaseInfo.o
      "_strlen", referenced from:
          _cs_strdup in utils.o
          _SStream_concat0 in SStream.o
          _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
          _PPC_printInst in PPCInstPrinter.o
          _Sparc_printInst in SparcInstPrinter.o
          _Sparc_map_hint in SparcMapping.o
      "_strncmp", referenced from:
          _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
      "_strncpy", referenced from:
          _cs_disasm in cs.o
          _fill_insn in cs.o
          _cs_disasm_iter in cs.o
      "_strrchr", referenced from:
          _ARM_post_printer in ARMInstPrinter.o
          _AArch64_post_printer in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _PPC_post_printer in PPCInstPrinter.o
      "_strstr", referenced from:
          _AArch64_printInst in AArch64InstPrinter.o
          _PPC_post_printer in PPCInstPrinter.o
          _printAliasInstr in SparcInstPrinter.o
      "_vsnprintf", referenced from:
          _cs_vsnprintf in cs.o
         (maybe you meant: _cs_vsnprintf)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    make: *** [libcapstone.dylib] Error 1
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libcapstone.dylib'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-install-hfg12cnd/capstone/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-record-l5k9b1g9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gg/v_3n0tps1zsbm17vmkmshp640000gn/T/pip-install-hfg12cnd/capstone/
```

I’ve also tried `brew install pwntools`, which says that it is already installed, but `import pwn` in python still fails with a “no module named pwn” error.
I thought it might be a temporary bug in capstone, but this has not worked for a few weeks now so that seems unlikely.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: The problem is that the package is trying to be built against `i386` and apparently that's no longer an option with the `SDK` your OS is using. Maybe try switching to an earlier one with `i386` symbols included and try it then...

Comment: The macOS 10.14 SDK no longer contains support for compiling 32-bit applications. If developers need to compile for i386, Xcode 9.4 or earlier is required. (39858111)
Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes

Comment: I thought pwntools isn't compatible with python 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`capstone==3.0.5` still tries to build for both i386 and x86_64, this is already fixed on master and will be released with the next version. Looking at the [`Makefile`](https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/blob/3.0.5/Makefile), there are two possibilities:

1. Turn off `MACOS_UNIVERSAL`:

   ```
   $ MACOS_UNIVERSAL=no pip install capstone
   ```
2. Install the development version from current master branch, with `LIBARCHS` already adapted for Mojave:

```
    $ pip install "git+https://github.com/aquynh/capstone.git#egg=capstone&subdirectory=bindings/python"
```

Make sure you use quotes in the last command or escape the ampersand (`&`), otherwise bash will cut the command and run in background instead.

Once `capstone` is installed, you will have to deal with `unicorn` in the same manner and finally should be able to install `pwntools`. I didn't test it anymore, but the one-liner for the installation will be

```
$ MACOS_UNIVERSAL=no pip install pwntools
```

Comment: Thanks! This was extremely helpful, I did need to add `--user`, but otherwise this worked.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I was able to install pwntools in Mojave with $ MACOS_UNIVERSAL=no pip install pwntools. What are the effects of setting MACOS_UNIVERSAL=no in this specific case?

Comment: @GiovanniRomio you won't get the [universal binaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary), only for the x86_64 arch. However, if in doubt whether you need it, then most surely you don't since Apple drops 32bit support anyway.